# Passing MYSQL Value from PHP Page jQuery Iframe

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, iframe

I am facing a challenge on how to pass a value from the the div into the iframe. For your information, the `<?php echo row['info_id']; ?>` hold a multiple value, so when the button was clicked it will get the database's info_id and updated into the jQuery iframe.

After the iframe get the value  it will be required to send it to my another page info.php using the iframe.

But I am having some problem to pass the value into the jQuery iframe where it will be read using the GET method.

**Index.php Page**

```
function toggleDivs() {
  var infoDetail = $('#infoDetail').html();
  $("#iframecall").html('<iframe src="info.php?new_id=' +  infoDetail + '" />'); 
}

$('.buttonClicked').live('click',function(){
   toggleDivs();
});    

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_01);           

<span class='buttonClicked'>
  <ul<li><div id='infoDetail'><?php echo $row['info_id']; ?></div></li></ul>
</span>



 **info.php**
 $connect = new doConnect(); 
 $info_id=$_GET['new_id']; 
 $sql_01 = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE info_id = $info_id";
```

Comment: You're missing the `$` sign in front of `row['info_id'];`. Maybe that is the reason why the value is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `$` sign in front of `row['info_id'];`. Maybe that is the reason why the value is not displayed?

```
<span class='buttonClicked'>
  <ul<li><div id='infoDetail'><?php echo $row['info_id']; ?></div></li></ul>
</span>                                # ^ missing?
```

To find these kind of errors, you should enable [PHP Error Reporting and logging](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and then watch your PHP error log. Look especially for *warnings and notices*. So [enable warnings and notices](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) as well for error reporting. Always write code that is free of warnings and notices, then you can more quickly identify problems.

php.ini settings for development:

```
; report all sort of errors, including notices and strict errors
error_reporting = -1
error_log = /path/to/your/php_error_log
```

then you can keep track of your error log like this:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/php_error_log
```

Comment: Hi @hakre, thx for the reply. Oo I forgot to put in the $ in this example. In my code there is $ in it. Think I left out some portion here. After the iframe get the value <?php echo $row['info_id']; ?> it will be required to send it to my another page info.phh with iframe where in this case I use the following code to get the URL value                       $connect = new doConnect();
$info_id=$_GET['new_id'];                                                          $sql_01 = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE info_id = $info_id ";

Comment: Are you looking for PHP errors? You should really do this at first. You can then add the errors to your question. And correct the code in your question, not here in a comment. It's important for others to answer your question that you're as precise as possible about the error/problem you have as well as being as compact as possible.

Comment: Hi @hakre noted. I will edit the question with the corrected code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleDivs() {
  var infoDetail = $('#infoDetail').html();
  $("#iframecall").html('<iframe src="info.php?new_id=' +  infoDetail + '" />'); 
}


$('.buttonClicked').live('click',function(){
   toggleDivs();
});    

<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_01);           
?>

<span class='buttonClicked'>
  <ul<li><div id='infoDetail'><?php echo $row['info_id']; ?></div></li></ul>
</span>
```